# Using scipy.interpolate.interp1d to calculate the x value where y =0.95

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have two arrays for x and y. I do not have a relationship between the two arrays but I want to be able to linearly interpolate between the points to y=f(x) so I can then calculate the x value where y = 0.95. The method I have used so far is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d    

def NearestValue(array,value):
#returns the index of the element of the array which is closest to value

idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
return idx

x =[[   0. ],[   9.9],[  19.8],[  31.5],[  41.9],[  49.1],[  59. ],[  70. ],[  80.4],[ 100. ]]

y= [ 0.011905, 0.140795, 0.600562, 0.757247, 0.874564, 0.934559, 0.961719, 0.986099,  0.990284, 0.998254]

f = interp1d(x,y)

x_new  = np.linspacex(x[0],x[9],1000)
y_new = f(x_new)

NearestIndex = NearestValue(y_new,0.95)

x_nearest = x_new[NearestIndex]
```

This method returns the value from x_new which has the closest corresponding y_new value closest to 0.95. Is there a way which I can calculate the x value where y is exactly 0.95?

Comment: In my current scipy implementation (0.19.0) , your code gives an error because of the dimensions of `x` and `y`. Please also check that the indentation in your function is missing. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is as simple as interpolating `x` as a function of `y` (I also needed to flatten `x` to avoid errors):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d    

def NearestValue(array,value):
    #returns the index of the element of the array which is closest to value

    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return idx

x =[[   0. ],[   9.9],[  19.8],[  31.5],[  41.9],[  49.1],[  59. ],[  70. ],[  80.4],[ 100. ]]

y= [ 0.011905, 0.140795, 0.600562, 0.757247, 0.874564, 0.934559, 0.961719, 0.986099,  0.990284, 0.998254]

f = interp1d(y, np.array(x).flatten())

print (f(0.95))
for i,_ in enumerate(y):
    print (_,  x[i][0], f(_))
```

EDIT: I have taken the liberty of replacing the last line of code provided by the answerer with three lines which show how nicely this solution works. They produce the following output.

```
54.728346833578776
0.011905 0.0 0.0
0.140795 9.9 9.9
0.600562 19.8 19.8
0.757247 31.5 31.5
0.874564 41.9 41.9
0.934559 49.1 49.1
0.961719 59.0 59.0
0.986099 70.0 70.0
0.990284 80.4 80.4
0.998254 100.0 100.0
```